# Matlab ksdensity for bivariate data with more evaluation points

Tags: matlab, statistics, kernel-density

I'm running Matlab code for kernel density, i.e., `[f,xi] = ksdensity(x)`, where `x` is a two column bivariate data. The resulting output `f` is the density vector, while `xi` is the meshgrid of evaluation points that is 30x30 in dimension. See the documentation here: [Link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html).

I'm trying to increase number of evaluation points that I receive from this code. There is an option mentioned in the documentation called `'NumPoints'` that is only applicable for univariate data. Is there an option or ways that I can increase the meshgrid points of evaluation points of bivariate data to, say, 100x100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the optional second input argument [`pts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html#inputarg_pts) to specify the range and number of the output points in your grid. See [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html#bu5lcsb) in the documentation. Depending on your input data, you could specify something like this:

```
pts = [linspace(min(x(:,1)),max(x(:,1)),1000).' linspace(min(x(:,2)),max(x(:,2)),1000).'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NumPoints` is `npoints` in the `ksdensity()`. e.g., `[f,xi] = ksdensity(x, 'npoints', 1000)` will return 1000 points of xi and f.